# How to limit the frequency of asking for permission to set a reminder - Alexa Skill?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, reminders

In the Alexa reminder guidelines it states:

"You do not want your customers to feel inundated with offers to set reminders if they have previously declined permission, as they may choose to disable the skill. If a customer says "No," they should not receive another offer for at least 7 days."

How do I write the code so that it knows to wait 7 days before asking again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the user's choice and the date, most probably in a database. Then you can check in your skill in each new session if 7 days have already passed since the last time the user has been asked.

The actual code depends on the programming language and database you are working with. Here is an official tutorial how to store and retrieve values using the SDK for node.js and Amazon S3 for persistence:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/tutorials-code-samples/build-an-engaging-alexa-skill/module-5